# CSV has number values with 1000 separator as comma. When these are stored as String by OpenCSV, how do I get back the actual value?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

This is how my CSV looks

```
ACV:    75,624.32
TCV:    136,315.64
ARR:    60,691.32
```

I am using OpenCSV to read the CSV.
Such that get(2)[1] stores 60,691.32.

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "thecsv.csv";
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(path));
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(reader);
List<String[]> csvBody = csvReader.readAll();
```

Now when I am printing get(2)[1] it prints **13,142.40** and **not** **60,691.32**.

```
System.out.println(csvBody.get(2)[1]);
```

The number is converted to String by OpenCSV.

How can I print the exact 60,691.32 from the CSV while using OpenCSV?

Comment: The comma is not being used as a separator in the provided CSV. No idea where the number is coming from but comma-filled entries are typically escaped in CSVs using quotation marks.

Comment: OpenCSV doesn't convert anything to String. It reads from a text file that's a big unique String, and gives you substrings of that big String. With possible decoding such as replacing "" with a single " when appropriate, but that's text decoding, not converting a data type to another, as it has no such notion.